# Add a new line before and after the <div> tag in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, reformat

Here is my current HTML code in PhpStorm:

```
<body>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</body>
```

When I Reformat Code, I would like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Empty line here in PhpStorm -->
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <!-- Empty line here in PhpStorm -->
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <!-- Empty line here in PhpStorm -->
</body>
```

I've been looking for hours in the HTML Code Style, but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Why don't use the <br> tag ??

Comment: I want to add a new line before and after the <div> tag in the IDE (when I use the Reformat Code action). I don't want to add a new line in the browser.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. It's called 'JSLint' the plugin that you want to disable...

Comment: @Liuk I cannot find this plugin nor in the Marketplace nor in the Installed plugins.

Comment: Try File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML > *Other* tab. Find "Insert new line before:" field and add `div` there. It should work ideally, but not on my installation for some reason.

Comment: @Ástþór Yes, I already did that. And it doesn't work for me too. :(

Comment: This option inserts a new line (moves a tag to a new line), it's not supposed to add an empty line.

Comment: @Oksana Thank you for clarifying that. Do you know how to add an empty line?